# Could this be a cosmic ray hit on my cameras sensor (CMOS, DSLR)?

Tags: photography, cosmic-ray

While taking pictures of the bubble nebula I noticed a very strange artifact on only one of my pictures. It can't be a satellite since its not a straight line and this is a 90s exposure that should make a line much longer. Also I doubt this is just readout noise from the camera (image is unstretched, unedited) since hot pixels don't form lines. So could this be a cosmic ray hit? If not does anyone have an idea what this could be?

The image was taken with my Canon 7D Mark II @ISO1600, 90s exposure.
Celestron C8 SGT (XLT), Celestron Advanced VX

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could it be something closer to earth like dust/speck of dirt/pollen/bug eyeball/sap/water droplet/etc that was on the lens and shifted during the exposure?

Comment: @iMerchant I highly doubt that, since it looks like something that was smaller than 1 pixel and still extremly sharp (compare it to the stars in the background). From this I concluded it must be something on the sensor of the camera, not something that came through the optics

Comment: I'll let others give definitive answer to this, but cosmic rays can leave tracks on ccd.  The fact it is not straight suggests a rather loe energy electron, rather than a high speed muon or similar.

Comment: Since it is very narrow, i think it must be something inside the camera, as an thing outdide would be blurred by imperfection of the lens. Some kind of stray elecron seems most likely

Comment: @RononDex: You could test the hypothesis that it's a cosmic, if you manage to repeat the same observation in the same field with the same parameters as given.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape Aren't cosmic ray hits kind of random? If so how would a repeat of the same show its validity?

Comment: @RononDex: If it's not there the second time, it was a cosmic. That's at least the usual assumption. Of course it could be also any other kind of non-repeatable event on your lens, but cosmics are the most frequent.

Comment: To me it looks like an airplane taking a curve (red-green-red).

Comment: @ott-- it seems unlikely that it has been something that I saw through the telescope, because it is completly sharp and not washed out like the stars in the background.

Comment: Possibly a grain of dust burning up as it entered the atmosphere.

Comment: The word you are looking for is "meteor", and I hardly think that's what it looks like on the picture.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a track about 50 pixels long, at [4.1 $\mu m$ per pixel](https://photographylife.com/reviews/canon-7d-mark-ii) that's 200 $\mu m$ in the plane of the sensor.

It's about 1 pixel wide, quite lumpy, and seems to change direction a bit. It really fits the description of an ionizing particle. There are multiple possible sources,

I'm pretty sure @JamesK has nailed it as an electron, but what else can we learn? There must be some way to get a *very rough* idea of how many $e^- h^+$ pairs correspond to a fully exposed pixel at "@ISO1600", then we could convert it to a dE/dx and see if it's minimum ionizing or if it's much higher.

Going diagonally, with a density of 2.3 g/cm${}^3$ that's about 1.3 mg/cm${}^2$ areal density per pixel. A [minimum ionizing particle] at 1.5 MeV / g cm${}^2$ would deposit only about 2000 eV which would make less than 1000 $e^- h^+$ pairs. That might correspond to a bright pixel. It's not out of the question that it's a minimum ionizing particle.

Comment: That's a very interesting read. If it might help you for further analysis, this is a page that analysis the sensor of my camera really deeply (with all the different read noise, gain, etc for each iso setting): http://www.clarkvision.com/reviews/evaluation-canon-7dii/

Alternatively this is another page with some more info: http://www.sensorgen.info/CanonEOS-7D-Mark-II.html

**Note that this image was taken while the sensor was at a temperature of around 34°C**

Comment: @RononDex looks like 2230 $e^-$ is the maximum value at ISO 1600 so indeed it could be a minimum ionizing particle! Thanks!